# selecting data from mysql table based on a date column and condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in mysql table `PACKAGES` as `SERVICE_EXPIRY_DATE` which holds a date time value.

Now I want to match only those records whose `SERVICE_EXPIRY_DATE` is coming within the next 15 days from the moment of querying.

How can I match those columns.

Comment: [BY reading that how to ask a good question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Worth a [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272335/mysql-select-last-7-days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by using intervals

```
WHERE `SERVICE_EXPIRY_DATE` BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
```

Look at MySql documentation for more reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html