# How to SELECT the last 30 days records from SQL, including days with zero?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to SELECT from my table the last 30 day records. My queries looks like this:

```
SELECT DATE(o_date) as date, count(id) AS sum FROM customers WHERE o_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW() GROUP BY o_date
```

Or this:

```
SELECT DATE(o_date) AS date, COUNT(id) AS sum FROM customers WHERE o_date >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -30 DAY GROUP BY DATE(o_date)
```

I want to create a list with dates and count of id-s.

But where I dont have any records in exact  day, the query just skip that date. But I want to insert there a zero.

Example:

| id | o_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-11-23 |
| 2 | 2021-11-22 |
| 3 | 2021-11-20 |
| 4 | 2021-11-20 |
| 5 | 2021-11-19 |
| 6 | 2021-11-18 |
| 7 | 2021-11-18 |

The result will be this:

| date | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-11-23 | 1 |
| 2021-11-22 | 1 |
| 2021-11-20 | 2 |
| 2021-11-19 | 1 |
| 2021-11-18 | 2 |

But where I dont have records like in this example in 2021-11-21 how can I insert to the sum 0?

Thank you!

UPDATE:
I need this query for MariaDB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Select last 7 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272335/mysql-select-last-7-days)

Comment: SQL standard have no date type.

Comment: A related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272335/mysql-select-last-7-days

Comment: You need a number generator to generate date series for the missing dates on which you can left join and use sum on

Answer (score 1):

For MariaDB,

```
SELECT DATE(o_date) AS date, COUNT(id) AS sum FROM customers WHERE o_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
AND NOW();
```

**For SQL,**

```
SELECT DATE(o_date) AS date, COUNT(id) AS sum FROM customers WHERE DATEDIFF(day,o_date,GETDATE()) < 31
```

or

```
SELECT DATE(o_date) AS date, COUNT(id) AS sum FROM customers WHERE DATEDIFF(day,o_date,GETDATE()) between 0 and 30
```

Comment: I just updated the question. I need this query for MariaDB so the DATEDIFF only takes 2  two arguments. I tried this query:
SELECT DATE(o_date) AS date, COUNT(id) AS sum FROM customers WHERE DATEDIFF(o_date,CURDATE()) between 0 and 30
But in this case the result is only one row with today-s date.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could gather, it should be :

`SELECT * FROM customers WHERE o_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW();`

Link to almost 10 year old post:
[MySQL Query - Records between Today and Last 30 Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041575/mysql-query-records-between-today-and-last-30-days)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

SELECT DATE(o_date) AS date, COUNT(id) AS sum FROM customers WHERE o_date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)

Comment: FUNCTION xxxx.DATEADD does not exist :/

Comment: Sorry it was for sql server. In mysql, it is DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 DAY). Then the query will become SELECT DATE(o_date) AS date, COUNT(id) AS sum FROM customers WHERE o_date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 DAY). I have edited the comment

Answer (score 0):

Your real question seems to be about how to show all 30 days, even days with a zero value.

Since you are using MariaDB 10.0 or newer, there is a nifty trick to give all the days in a range:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT '2019-01-01' + INTERVAL seq-1 DAY  AS dates   FROM seq_1_to_31;
+-----------------------------------+
| dates                             |
+-----------------------------------+
| 2019-01-01                        |
| 2019-01-02                        |
| 2019-01-03                        |
| 2019-01-04                        |
| 2019-01-05                        |
| 2019-01-06                        |  etc.
```

So, what you do is

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( select using seq table ) AS dates
    JOIN ( your table ) AS yours ON dates.dy = yours.o_date
    WHERE ...
```

Your secondary question about how to ask for a date range -- both of your attempts give the same result with the same performance.