# How to fetch record where condition is current date + 7 must be equal to some column date value

Tags: sql, db2

could you please help me to write query for below condition,
i want to fetch record which meet the condition like (current date + 7) must be equal to sdate.
Ex:- suppose current date is 2022-02-23, then row 1 and row 4 should come.
suppose current date is 2022-02-25, then row 2 should come.

WB.DATA table

| PERIOD | HSID | SDATE | START |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-15 | 184 | 2022-03-03 | N |
| 2022-09-15 | 184 | 2022-03-05 | Y |
| 2022-09-15 | 183 | 2022-01-06 | N |
| 2022-09-15 | 183 | 2022-03-03 | Y |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Select last 7 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272335/mysql-select-last-7-days)

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE SDATE = CURRENT DATE + 7 DAYS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM {tablename} WHERE SDATE = (NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```